# Derived table in mysql showing error

Tags: mysql, sql

When I am using this derived table in my query in MYSQL it always pops up with the error `'' UNKNOWN COLUMN COMPANY.CNAME''` though in the database there is `CNAME` field present in COMPANY table:

Error:
[image: error]

Diagram:
[image: er diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error appears at first line. Try it by changing `company.cname` to `cname` or `t.cname`

```
select cname from
(
   select count(medication.id) as total, company.cname 
   from medication
   join company on medication.company_id = company.id
   group by company.cname
   order by count(medication.id) desc
   limit 1
) as t
```